# They were given either x and y OR They were given either x and y

Tags: grammar

Example: The state examinations to judge the teacher required showing the kids colored cards in either the blue or red condition.

[or]

The state examinations to judge the teacher required showing the kids colored cards in either the blue and red condition.

Comment: Is the title supposed to read "They were given either x ***or*** y OR They were given either x and y"?

Answer (score 2):

The former is correct, the latter one would also be correct in a sense that the ***either*** phrase is ***the blue and red condition***, and ***or*** phrase is missing such that the complete sentence would be like:

> The state examinations to judge the teacher required showing the kids colored cards in either ***the blue and red*** or ***the black and white*** condition.

Comment: Thank you! So its like: the kids were given pictures of either cats and dogs;

Comment: or : the kids were given pictures of either cats and dogs or turtles and ducks.

Comment: Either complete "The kids were given pictures of either cats and dogs" by adding remaining "or" phrase or change it like "the kids were given pictures of either cats or dogs.".

Comment: The only circumstances where 'either' and 'and' are used together is when at least one of the options is compound rather than simple. In your picture example you might have "The children were given pictures of either cats and dogs or of sheep and cattle." In this case there would have been one set of pictures showing cats and dogs and another set of pictures showing sheep and cattle. The children would have been given **either** pictures of cats and dogs **or** pictures of sheep and cattle. None of the children would have been given a picture of a sheepdog working a flock of sheep.